# Creating a year wise excel chart with twin axis?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

Is it possible to make a chart with main axis of amount and secondary axis of number ***year wise***? The data sheet has for each row, two columns of data ( Units sold & amount) under each column year.
I can make a chart with secondary axis for units and amount, but I cannot plot this year wise

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "year wise"? Also please share what could you achieve so far, and how you want to improve it.

Comment: I have unit sales and amount across 8 stores for past 7 years. I am trying to plot both the unit sales and the amount of all the stores across the years in one chart. I can only make this for one single year at a time. Either the unit + amount across stores for one year or Unit sales/amount across stores across years